# Prestashop add hyperlink or image to product features

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink, prestashop

Hello I'm trying to add a customized link to the product feature for prestashop.

Here is what i tried:

Edit `/classes/FeatureValue.php`

> // Lang fields

```
'value' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'required'
  => true, 'size' => 255),
```

to this

> // Lang fields

```
'value' => array('type' => self::TYPE_NOTHING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isAnything', 'required'
  => true, 'size' => 255),
```

Also this file: *`/themes/<your theme folder>/product.tpl`*

From:

```
{foreach from=$features item=feature}
                    <tr class="{cycle values="odd,even"}">
                        {if isset($feature.value)}
                        <td>{$feature.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</td>
                        <td>{$feature.value|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</td>
                        {/if}
                    </tr>
                    {/foreach}
```

To this:

```
{foreach from=$features item=feature}
                    <tr class="{cycle values="odd,even"}">
                        {if isset($feature.value)}
                        <td>{$feature.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</td>
                        <td>{$feature.value|escape:'UTF-8'}</td>
                        {/if}
                    </tr>
                    {/foreach}
```

And this file: *`admin1234/themes/default/template/controllers/products/features.tpl`*

Changed this:

```
<textarea class="custom_{$available_feature.id_feature}_ALL textarea-autosize"  name="custom_{$available_feature.id_feature}_ALL"
                                cols="40" style='background-color:#CCF' rows="1" onkeyup="{foreach from=$languages key=k item=language}$('.custom_{$available_feature.id_feature}_{$language.id_lang}').val($(this).val());{/foreach}" >{$available_feature.val[1].value|escape:'html':'UTF-8'|default:""}</textarea>
```

To this:

```
<textarea class="custom_{$available_feature.id_feature}_ALL textarea-autosize"  name="custom_{$available_feature.id_feature}_ALL"
                                cols="40" style='background-color:#CCF' rows="1" onkeyup="{foreach from=$languages key=k item=language}$('.custom_{$available_feature.id_feature}_{$language.id_lang}').val($(this).val());{/foreach}" >{$available_feature.val[1].value|escape:'UTF-8'|default:""}</textarea>
```

The problem is that when i add the value to the custom field, after i click save it disappears and it's not inserted into the database.
But if i add the hyperlink to the defined features, then it's saved in the database and i can use it.
But since i want to add multiple hyperlinks/Height let's say i cannot make 100 combinations that are predefined.

If i was unclear i apologize and if you need more info, please let me know.
Prestashop version: 1.6.0.11

Answer (score 1):

Edite
Classes/Product.php

Find

```
Add new feature to product
```

and 2 line upper find

```
$row = array('id_feature_value' => (int)$id_value, 'id_lang' => (int)$lang, 'value' => pSQL($cust));
```

change with

```
$row = array('id_feature_value' => (int)$id_value, 'id_lang' => (int)$lang, 'value' => $cust);
```

I just remove 
and All other changes for yourself is True .with this change in 1.6 version Custom html work ok !
just clear Cache and fine . . .

for some reasone Check

```
/override/classes/
```

if you see Product.php and FeatureValue.php  do changes on them too